# Line form corner to corner

Tags: java, swing, drawing2d

I got a little problem, I think I made a mistake. Can you help me please? 
Question: I want to use specifix integers for drawing line and filling rectangle. I tried to do it, but line, using same coordinates as rectangle, is not from corner to another corner.

```
void draw(Graphics g) {

    int x = getWidth();//1920
    int y = getHeight();//1080
    int x0 = 10; int y0 = 10;


    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x0, y0, x0 + 1300, y0 + 800);    


    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    g.drawLine(x0, y0, x0 + 1300, y0 + 800);


}
```

image how it looks:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD9Rq.jpg]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to do it, but line, using same coordinates as rectangle

But both method don't use coordinates:

```
g.fillRect(x0, y0, x0 + 1300, y0 + 800);
```

The fillRect draws a rectangle from a starting point using a `width and height`.

```
g.drawLine(x0, y0, x0 + 1300, y0 + 800);
```

The drawLine draws a line between two points.

When drawing the rectangle the code should be:

```
//g.fillRect(x0, y0, x0 + 1300, y0 + 800);    
g.fillRect(x0, y0, 1300, 800);
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to use specific integers not ezual to zero...Can I do that? Or it will be always the same result?(not from corner to corner)?

Comment: Ah! Thanks you! Now I see! :)